# Lambda Function "unhashable type: Series" error

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am attempting to set the value of a column equal to "United States of America" if the first 3 characters of another column equal "USA", else I want to preserve the existing value of the column.

```
df['Country'] = df['Country ID'].map(lambda x: 'United States of America' if x[:3] == 'USA' else df['Country'])
```

However, this gives the error:

> unhashable type: 'Series'

I am unsure how to refer back to the column's original value if the if condition is not met.

Comment: Better `df['Country'] = df['Country'].mask(df['Country ID'].str[:3].eq('USA'), 'United States of America')`

Comment: @jezrael but this pulls back the Country ID if the condition is not met, rather than the original country name from df['Country']

Comment: Yop  I see, so use `.mask` solution

Comment: Out of interest, how would it be done using lambda?

Comment: Not tested `df['Country'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'United States of America' if x['Country ID'].str[:3] == 'USA' else x['Country'], axis=1)`